# ImportError: Cannot import name 'x'

Tags: python, importerror

Plenty of these threads but I'm still mega confused. I'm getting a ImportError and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Heres the error message:

```
  File "/app/src/pptxbuilder/app.py", line 85, in <module>
    __web_setup()
  File "/app/src/pptxbuilder/app.py", line 35, in __web_setup
    from pptxbuilder.views.home import home_bp
  File "/app/src/pptxbuilder/views/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_bp
  File "/app/src/pptxbuilder/views/builder.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pptxbuilder.app import app
  File "/app/src/pptxbuilder/app.py", line 85, in <module>
    __web_setup()
  File "/app/src/pptxbuilder/app.py", line 36, in __web_setup
    from pptxbuilder.views.builder import builder_bp
ImportError: cannot import name 'builder_bp'
```

Here are my paths:

```
src\pptxbuilder\app.py
src\pptxbuilder\views\builder.py
src\pptxbuilder\views\home.py
```

In 'builder.py' I have this variable

```
builder_bp = Blueprint('builder', __name__)
```

In 'home.py' I have this variable

```
home_bp = Blueprint('home', __name__)
```

And I'm running the line below in 'app.py'

```
'from pptxbuilder.views.builder import builder_bp'
```

Comment: Can you add the content of `builder.py` to your question? This is going to be awfully hard to debug if we can't see what you're doing.

Comment: @josh theres tons of code in builder.py but I've added more info, hopefully it'll help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove pptxbuilder.

```
from views.builder import builder_bp
```

Simple example, but the concept should be the same. Your exact code will be different of course.
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! 1 question, I'm guessing importing variables instead of functions will work with this snippet too right?

Comment: @Boosted_d16 if that worked please accept this as the answer